# Linear Programming feasible using linprog and unfeasible using Gurobi in Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, gurobi

I have the following very simple linear programming problem to solve in Matlab

```
clear

%The unknown
%x=[x1,...,x10];

%The constraints
%x2+x8=Phi12
%x3+x7=Phi21
%x5=infvalue;
%x10=infvalue;

%The known parameters 
Phi12=-3.3386;
Phi21=3.0722;
infvalue=50;

sizex=10; %size of the unknown
```

The problem admits a solution.

When I implement this LP using `linprogr` it find a solution.

When I implement this LP using the Gurobi solver it tells me that the problem is unfeasible.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code.

```
beq=[Phi12; Phi21; infvalue; infvalue];

rAeq=[ 1 1 ...
       2 2 ...
       3 ...
       4]; 

cAeq=[ 2 8 ...
       3 7 ...
       5 10]; 

fillAeq=[1 1 ...
         1 1 ...
         ones(1,2)];

Aeq=sparse(rAeq, cAeq,fillAeq, size(beq,1),sizex); 
Aeqfull=full(Aeq);

%linprogr
f=zeros(sizex,1);
xlinprog = linprog(f,[],[],Aeqfull,beq);

%Gurobi
clear model;
model.A=Aeq;
model.rhs=beq; 
model.sense=repmat('=', size(Aeq,1),1);
model.obj=f;
resultgurobi=gurobi(model);
```

During my attempts to understand what is going on: if I put any **positive** value in place of `-3.3386`, then Gurobi works perfectly. Whta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab's `linprog` it holds -inf <= x <= inf by default for your variable x, while for Gurobi it is x >= 0. Due to this you need to set the lower bound for your variables to -Inf:

```
model.lb = -inf * ones(sizex, 1);
```